# Mysql Fulltext search with different number of columns

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I've been taking my first stab at Fulltext searching and am having trouble getting the query to work. Here's the new code I've been trying (from a PHP file):

```
$browse_all_query = "(SELECT master_id, title, series_id, series_number, year, date, day, month, speaker_id, speaker2_id, speaker3_id " .
                    "FROM master " .
                    "WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ($where_clause)) " .
                    "UNION " .
                    "(SELECT camp_name, camp_id " .
                    "FROM camp " .
                    "WHERE MATCH (camp_name) AGAINST ($where_clause)) " .
                    "UNION " .
                    "(SELECT subject_name, subject_id " .
                    "FROM subject " .
                    "WHERE MATCH (subject_name) AGAINST ($where_clause)) " .
                    "UNION " .
                    "(SELECT speaker_id, s_title, f_name, m_name, l_name, l_name2 " .
                    "FROM speaker " .
                    "WHERE MATCH (s_title, f_name, m_name, l_name, l_name2) AGAINST ($where_clause)) " .
                    "UNION " .
                    "(SELECT series_title, series_id " .
                    "FROM series " .
                    "WHERE MATCH (series_title) AGAINST ($where_clause)) ";
```

Now, I understand that a big issue for me here is that I have different numbers of columns in my select statements as well as different data types. What I need is to figure out how I can pull all the information I need from all the columns I've selected, yet still use fulltext search.  This is an online audio library. I'm using a regular WHERE/LIKE setup now, but unfortunately using that method, searching for one speaker's name (Glenn Clark) brings up results for "glenn" and "clark" wherever they are used as I sanitize and separate my keywords....not to mention that the "speaker" table has separate columns for first name and last name.

What would be the best way around this?

My table structure is:

1. Master (the main table with 13 columns)
2. Speaker (6 columns)
3. Camp (3 columns)
4. Series (6 columns)
5. Subject (2 columns)

In my current code I was selecting all the extra bits of information not directly relative to the search at the same time I ran the search, as I use those bits (like all the "id" fields) to output all the information I needed for the results as seen here:
[image]

Am I needing additional queries or am I going about this completely the wrong way.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ...And using a separate fulltext search system like lucene is not an option with this internet host

Comment: in a similar situation i wrote my own internal search engine, firstly bringing the data from multiple tables\databases in to one table, then i could search in that one table.

Comment: I think generating my own search engine is beyond what I want to do at this point, but I appreciate the input and will look at that as a solution later.